# Inside (if) 2 arguments not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've a code working on most browsers except firefox.
That is launched from a submit form. I just want to give "agree" as true and then close window when accepted.
If I delete the closing argument will do it right on both FF and Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmSubmit() {
    var agree = confirm("¿Estas seguro de anular esta reserva?");
    if (agree) {
        window.parent.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is having the two options inside the if (1. window.parent.close() 2. return true), but the window.close() works okay on both browsers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343744/close-parent-window-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks for replying. My problem is not about closing the window. It does it right, it's about the other return.

Comment: You cannot close a window programmatically on firefox

Comment: Please clarify `both options inside the if`

Comment: @Satpal edited for a better explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @lorenz-meyer It works closing the window, that's fine.

Comment: So the `else` statement does not work? In what way does it not work?

Comment: @putvande The `else` works. I have a `onClick="return confirmSubmit()"` at the bottom but accepting the dialog only closes the window, doesn't send the form. But in IE and Chrome works fine.

Comment: @Aaron why don't you try to create a **simple** jsfiddle.net to show your problem, because I've read your question 3 times and I can't understand where is the problem and what is the code purpose...

Comment: @toni-almeida Thanks for replying. I tried to jsfiddle.net but don't know how to properly make it run without php. Instead I've pasted full code here [link]http://tny.cz/29294c7e . Hope it helps you to help me :) Function is on line 145 and submit button on 253

Comment: @ToniAlmeida Not sure if I'm mentioning you right. sorry

Comment: I finally sorted it out. Actually I'm calling the

`window.parent.close();`

When drawing the form results div of confirmation. So the initial scripts is finally this way:

`function confirmSubmit()
{
var agree=confirm("¿Are you sure?");
if (agree) {
   return true;
}
else{
    return false ;
}
}`

Thanks for all your help and replys. I cannot answer my own question so if someone can, please do that.

Comment: Nice! now you can simplify your code like this: `function confirmSubmit() { return confirm("¿Are you sure?"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` works sometimes.  A better method, is to explicitly tell the event to prevent the default action.  Here's an example using addEventListener.

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", confirmSubmit);

function confirmSubmit(e) {
    var agree = confirm("¿Estas seguro de anular esta reserva?");
    console.log(agree);
    if (agree) {
        window.parent.close();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Also note the answers in [Close Parent window in fireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343744/close-parent-window-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually this code also works on Chrome but not in FF. It closes the window ok but it doesn't really confirm the form. 
Sorry for my inexperience.
May should I post the entire code? It's quite big and don't know if it's allowed correctly here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally sorted it out.
Actually I'm calling the

```
window.parent.close();
```

When drawing the form results div of confirmation. 
So the initial scripts is finally this way:

```
function confirmSubmit()
{
var agree=confirm("¿Are you sure?");
if (agree) {
   return true;
}
else{
    return false ;
}
}
```

Thanks for all your help and replys.